# $routeProvider - correct URL but no page is loaded

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm new in angular.js and I want to build my first site (music site) and
I'm trying to use the $routeProvider, and when i run the site i see the correct url that it should be but there is nothing in the page.

This is the "myApp":

```js
var SplayApp = angular.module('SplayApp', ['ngRoute']);

SplayApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.
 when('\Main', {
  controller : 'MainController',
  templateUrl : '\partials\Main.html'
 }).
 otherwise({
  redirectTo : '\Main'
 });
}]);
```

This is the MainController :

```js
SplayApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.songs = [{
 'band' : 'Some band',
 'songName' : 'Some name',
 'fileName' : 'The file url in my computer'
},
{...},
{...},
{...}];
});
```

And this is the Main.html that i want to load (very simple page) :

```js
<div ng-repeat="song in songs">
 <audio controls>
    <source src={{song.fileName}} type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

And this is the Index.html that i run :

```html
<html ng-app="SplayApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/SplayApp.js"></script>
 <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-view>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: when I'm trying to open only the Main.html it does load and i see the page.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change all the backslashes into slashes.

`\Main` to `/Main` and `\partials\Main.html` to `/partials/Main.html`

That should be it.

Comment: I tried this already and it's looking for the Main.html in the wrong place..here is the error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/partials/Main.html

Comment: What angular version do you use ?!